# about implementing programs made using java once "done"

Tags: java, implementation

i just started java after fiddling with turbo c and c++. I just found out that java can't be turned to an executable file natively. It's possible with the use of wrappers though, but isn't really advisable. So, im making some simple apps with mysql as my database. If ever i'm done with this? What should i do next? do i still need to install an IDE such as eclipse or netbeans to run this project of mine? I mean not all users know that except those who actually study programming, most people only know double clicking an icon right? You guys get what I'm saying? IF not pleease just ask i can ellaborate or explain more. TY!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an IDE.  You just need a JRE (or a JDK) to be installed on the system in order to run Java applications.

There are two approaches to this:

- Create an installer that will (if necessary) install a JRE that it has embedded in it.  There are a few installer generators that support this kind of thing.
- Instruct the user to download and install a JRE for themselves.  It is not hard.  Any *slightly* computer literate user should be able to do this.  (For Linux it typically just means running "yum" or "apt-get" or the equivalent.  For Windows, you download and run a Java installer from the Oracle website.)

---

I've glossed over the issue of how you package up your software and its dependencies.  If you are using an installer generator, it can handle most of that ... once you've put your code into a JAR file.  Alternatively, it could be as simple as putting all of the relevant JARs, config files and launch scripts into a ZIP or TAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Your java code at IDE such as eclipse can be exported to a java archive  "jar" file , this kind of files can be used as executable as long as java platform is installed  in user's PC

Go to[image] your project and write -click export , then choose JAR file

Answer (score 0):

You can export your code into a .jar file, and then type into notepad:

```
@echo off
java -jar myJarFile.jar
```

Save this as a .bat file in the same directory as your .jar. You can use that to run your java, like an .exe, as long as they are in the same directory.